# Using method as autoform type and add postId

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

When I use a quickform in `autoform` to insert docs in a collection, it seems the inserted docs are flickering shortly after insertion. I have read that this is due to latency compensation. I have also read that I have to insert through the server if I want to avoid the flickering. Therefore, I use

```
{{> quickForm id="demo" schema=schemaFromJSON type="method" meteormethod="demoSubmission"}}
```

having the method `demoSubmission` to insert the doc:

```
Meteor.methods({
   demoSubmission: function (attr) {
       check(attr, Collection.simpleSchema());

       var doc = _.extend(attr, {
          createdBy: user._id,
          createdAt: new Date
       });

       return Collection.insert(doc);
   }
}
```

is this the correct way to insert using autoform? Should the method be defined in server, client, or shared code?

My problem is that if I want to create a comment using this method type, I don't know how to add the postId to which the comment belongs.

Can I pass the id through quickform?

```
{{> quickForm (...) postId=myPostId}}
```

and then get the `postId` parameter in the method?